# Rank of the diagonal submatrices of full rank square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

For a square matrix $A$ in shape $n\times n$, select $m$ row indexes and the same $m$ column indexes $(m\leq n)$ to get a square submatrix - we call it a "diagonal submatrix". The question is, if for a square matrix $A$, each of its diagonal submatrices is of full rank, then what special property would $A$ have?

For example, if $A$ is a diagonal matrix (with only diagonal entries non-zero), then $A$ satisfies the above requirements.

Comment: Any non-singular matrix is similar to a matrix with all nonzero principal minors. Exactly such terms are well known.

Comment: @kabenyuk - Maybe i didn't get your meaning? e.g. A=[[1,1,0], [1,1,1], [0,1,0]], A has rank 3 (non-singular). But pick the 1st and 3rd rows & columns, the diagonal submatrix [[1,0],[0,0]] is not full rank.

Comment: One more time.
First, I draw your attention to common terminology.
Second, the following statement is true:
Every non-singular matrix is similar to a matrix in which all the principal minors are non-zero and therefore the corresponding matrices have full rank.
Two square matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar if there exists a matrix $T$ such that $B=TAT^{-1}$.